# How to Prove $\{Ax + b \mid Fx = g \}$ is Affine?

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

In order to prove $\{Ax + b \mid Fx = g \}$ is affine, is the following sufficient for the proof?

$\{A\left(\theta x_1+\left(1-\theta\right)x_2\right) + b \mid F\left(\theta x_1+\left(1-\theta\right)x_2\right) \stackrel{?}{=} g \}$

So,

$F\left(\theta x_1+\left(1-\theta\right)x_2\right)=\theta Fx_1+Fx_2-\theta Fx_2 = \theta g+g -\theta g=g$

Do we need to show the same thing for $A\left(\theta x_1+\left(1-\theta\right)x_2\right) + b$? In general, is applying the affine definition (which is sometimes hard) the only way to prove a set is affine?

Comment: It is not clear what $A,F,g,x$ are. Can you precise to which space they belong ?

Comment: Those are unspecified. I assumed $A$ and $F$ are matrices for linear transformation of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call $S=\{Ax+b\mid Fx=g\}$

Your title is misleading, what you are seemingly trying to do, is to prove that $S$ is **convex**.

In this case let's take two points $(X,Y)\in S^2$ and $t\in[0,1]$

$\begin{array}{ll}
Z &= tX+(1-t)Y\\
&= t(Ax+b)+(1-t)(Ay+b)\\
&= A(tx+(1-t)y)+b(t+(1-t))\\
&= Az+b\end{array}\qquad$ with $z=tx+(1-t)y$

Then $Fz=tFx+(1-t)Fy=tg+(1-t)g=g\qquad$ so $\quad Z\in S$.

Thus $S$ is convex.

---

Anyway, the proof for an affine space derived from $S$ should go like this:

Let's define $\vec{S}=\{Au\mid u\in\ker F\}$

Since $A,F$ are linear applications, then it is immediate that $\vec S$ is a vector space.

- $\vec 0\leftrightarrow u=0$
- $\vec U+\vec V\leftrightarrow Au+Av=A(u+v)$ and $F(u+v)=Fu+Fv=0+0=0$
- $\alpha\vec U\leftrightarrow \alpha Au=A(\alpha u)$ and $F(\alpha u)=\alpha Fu=\alpha.0=0$
- and so on...

Now we can verify that $S\times\vec S$ is affine

- $X+\vec 0=Ax+b+A0=Ax+b=X$
- $(X+\vec U)+\vec V=Ax+B+Au+Av=Ax+b+A(u+v)=X+(\vec U+\vec V)$
- $X-Y=Ax+b-Ay-b=A(x-y)=\vec U\in\vec S$ since $F(x-y)=Fx-Fy=g-g=0$

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prove $S=\{Ax + b \mid Fx = g \}$ is an affine set.

The proof is similar to those provided by @zwim, except that $t$ (or $\theta$) isn't constrained to be in $[0,1]$.

Take $C_1=Ax_1+b \in S$, $C_2=Ax_2+b \in S$, and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{align}
C_3 &= \theta C_1 + (1-\theta) C_2 \\
&= \theta (Ax_1+b) + (1-\theta) (Ax_2+b) \\
&= \theta Ax_1 + \theta b + (1-\theta) Ax_2 + (1-\theta) b \\
&= A (\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2) + (\theta + (1-\theta)) b \\
&= A x_3 + b \\
\end{align}

where $x_3 = (\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2)$.

Given $Fx_1=g$ and $Fx_2=g$, check if $Fx_3\stackrel{?}{=}g$:

\begin{align}
Fx_3 &= F (\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2) \\
&= \theta F x_1 + (1-\theta) F x_2 \\
&= \theta g + (1-\theta) g \\
&= g \\
\end{align}

Therefore $S$ is an affine set.